# Object Oriented module/definition for networking devices/topology?

Tags: oop, networking, automation, snmp

Is there any module/definition available for a class/schema for representing the topology, connection, access details etc of networking devices ? The intent is to use this for automation, and to manage routers/servers as objects rather than as tcl keyed lists/arrays which gets unwieldy.

Comment: @David Just FYI, I am not looking for MIB support (though I understand that some of the snmp tools may have the OO design I am looking for).

Answer (score 0):

Look at SNMP (Simple Network Management Protocol). Most network devices and services, from IIS to Cisco routers, provide some sort of SNMP interface that may provide the capabilities for which you are searching. Specific implementations and capabilities vary between vendors and devices, but the protocol is standardized and very widely implemented.

Answer (score 0):

The word topology in the context of communication nework refers to the way in which how devices are connectd over a network. Its important types are
BUS
RING
STAR
etc

Comment: I am not looking for the literal definition :) I am looking for a class definition or design to represent networking devices and their attributes such as interfaces, cards, management access info, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [MIB2](http://www.alvestrand.no/objectid/1.3.6.1.2.1.html) (SNMP based).  You should note there exists 10's of different MIBs to representing various networking technologies / solutions. You can even devise your private MIB to suit your needs.

You should refer to relevant IETF drafts explaining the nomenclature used in MIBs (when I find the reference, I'll post it).

I could also suggest you perform searches on keywords such as "OSS", "Network Management", "NMS".